# Inside a form, can I make two api calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, api

So the thing is I am making a form that will save the name and image path of an object in the database. Additionally, I need to save the images in my directory so I can retrieve them later on.
Where can I add, in this case, a new api call to "http://localhost:5000/products"?

```
  return (
    <>
      <form
        className="modal-container"
        action="http://localhost:5000/upload"
        method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <div className="modal-box">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name of the product"
            className="btn-input-text"
            name="product-name"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            className="btn-input-image"
            name="product-image"
            onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
          <span className="btn-close" onClick={onClose}></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
```

Add a product:

```
app.post("/products", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, description, image } = req.body;
    const newProduct = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO products (product_name, product_description, product_image) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *",
      [name, description, image]
    );
    res.json(newProduct.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

Save the image in my directory (using multer):

```
app.post("/upload", upload.single("product-image"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  res.send("Image Uploaded");
});
```

Thank you !

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do.  Normally a given form will be sent with the POST request once with all of its contents to a single API on your server.  That API can then pick out the various pieces of the form and do whatever it needs to with them.

Comment: @jfriend00 true, my bad, I added both calls to the description, no idea how to join them though T_T

Comment: As I said in my comment above, you can send both images and other form elements in one form to one API.  If you want to make separate API calls from the client, then you will probably want to use two separate forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both jobs with one api call. Your image is saved in directory via the upload middleware.

You can access details of file inside post route by `req.file` and content of other fields by `req.body`.

You can merge post routes into one upload route. You will also be able to save file details in the database which you can use to retrieve file later. E.g `rq.file.originalname`

```
    app.post("/upload", upload.single("product-image"), async (req, res) => {
    const { name, description} = req.body;
const image = req.file.originalname;
        const newProduct = await pool.query(
          "INSERT INTO products (product_name, product_description, product_image) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *",
          [name, description, image]
        );
        
          console.log(req.file);
          res.send("Image Uploaded");
        });
```

Comment: Yup! I did this. Didn't know about req.file. Thanks for showing me how to do it! In fact, I am using the req.file.originalname

Answer (score 0):

With React you can bypass the default behaviour of a form submitting data with a POST request to one API Endpoint and write your own handleSubmit function that uses two APIs instead.

Comment: Yeah, a bit tricky with file uploads though and you can't just grab the data directly and send it directly via Javascript like you can with other field types...

Comment: Oh, I  missed the file upload, as it said, that in the form the file path will be saved. In this case I would not deactivate default behaviour and use it to upload the file, but still add a onClick function to handle the second API call.